# ionic actionsheet cancelButton not shown on android

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I looked at http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/KwBpRq?editors=101 , and I have not seen cancelButton on android. On iOS everything works fine. How can I display cancelButton?

```
$ionicActionSheet.show({
  titleText: 'ActionSheet Example',
  buttons: [
    { text: '<i class="icon ion-share balanced"></i> Share' },
    { text: '<i class="icon ion-arrow-move assertive"></i> Move' },
  ],
  destructiveText: 'Delete', // <<
  cancelText: 'Cancel',
  cancel: function() {
    console.log('CANCELLED');
  },
```

Comment: Let chrome attach to it see if there's any error in the console.

Comment: And to see if there's any wrong calculating in the DOM

Answer (score 12, accepted):

_action-sheet.scss has rule:

```
.platform-android .action-sheet-cancel {
    display: none;
}
```

To display cancelButton insert in .css/.scss file:

```
.platform-android .action-sheet-cancel {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: this answer is correct why don't you mark it correct :)

Comment: The reason why there is no cancel is because of material design https://material.google.com/components/bottom-sheets.html#bottom-sheets-modal-bottom-sheets